# Pop-up not showing (with magnific-popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I'm trying to implement [magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) on my website but for some reason my test image is not opening in popup mode. What could be the issue?
Many thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Document sans nom</title>
<!-- Scripts -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" /></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
          type: 'image',
          closeOnContentClick: true,
          mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
          image: {
            verticalFit: true
          }
      });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_b.jpg" title="Caption. Can be aligned it to any side.">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_s.jpg" width="75" height="75">
</a>consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the JavaScript console. You got an error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < testpopup.html:14
```

Click on the error message and it takes you to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
```

There is your problem, you have two opening script tags.

Answer (score 0):

you should put

```
(document).ready(function()
```

inside the `body`, not the `head`

Comment: and why should the OP do that?

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      closeOnContentClick: true,
      mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
      image: {
        verticalFit: true
      }
 });
```

Your problem, you have two opening script tags: `});`

The proper version of script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      closeOnContentClick: true,
      mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
      image: {
        verticalFit: true
      }
  });
});
```